# How to SELECT data using 2 tables and show data only from table 1

Tags: php

I have a table called student
within it are several fields including:

student_matric

I have another table called participation
within it are several fields including:

program_id

student_matric

status

query that i need is, it will show all data from the student table. it will check the students who participated in a program can no longer participate in the program.

it look like this,
After the add button is clicked .. status became join.. students who have chosen by lecture, can't be choosen again...
this system is used by lecture...

Comment: use a JOIN, SELECT from participation table, JOIN the student table. only disoplay the columns in student table. Have you tried doing this yourself yet, or are you just coming on here for the easy way out?

Comment: well your subject and last paragraph assume different scenarios: 1. to see a list of students already participating. 2. to exclude students from the list of to_be-participant (which presumes a list of non participating students) and if you mentioning a button - then i guess it should be done live on the page? - this is a project of it self...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (1) I understand correctly what you're trying to do; and (2) `student_matric` is a foreign key (or at least a reference field in the second table, then you can try doing something like:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ..., fieldN
  FROM student
 WHERE student_matric NOT IN (SELECT student_matric FROM participation WHERE progra_id=your_value)
```